# Why can't I retrieve custom environment variable?

Tags: powershell

I created a user environment variable `testPurpose`:

[image: test]

My script either doesn't display it if I call it like this:

```
$env:testPurpose
```

or if I try this way

```
$x = "testPurpose"
(get-item env:$x).Value
```

I get this error:

> get-item : Cannot find path 'Env:\testPurpose' because it does not exist.

Using `gci env:* | sort-object name`, I can clearly see it has been created for sure

[image: display envs]

So why can't I retrieve it? If I try this:

```
$env:ProgramData
```

I get back program data location printed just fine!

So I am positive it's not a command issue

Comment: Is it a -User- variable, or a -System- environment variable? It looks like a user variable, You likely want to create a system environment variable.

Comment: @HAL9256 yep user variable

Comment: Does making it a system variable help?

Comment: @HAL9256 nope, just tried and got same error

Comment: What does the code inside the script look like? what does `gci env:*` return from inside the script? I see the error message has a \ before the environment name.

Comment: @HAL9256 it returns back the env variables. The script just looks like this: $x = "testPurpose"
(get-item env:$x).Value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192926/discussion-between-hal9256-and-cataster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try restarting the PowerShell session.

Environment variables are loaded only at the start of the session, or run within the context of the session.

Answer (score 1):

You might have created them in the running process, which are only available to that session.  They also go away after yo close that PS window.  Try making it a machine-wide variable which should persist.

Note: I am not sure why you would want to create these rather than just creating the variable in the script, but to each their own.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("testPurpose", "TESTING", "Machine")
(Get-Item "env:testPurpose").Value
$testPurpose = "testPurpose"
(Get-Item env:$testPurpose).Value
```

Comment: actually the variable is a secret token for a vault, but of course for SO purposes here, i made it simple. my manager prefers storing it in machine as we are the only ones who can access the machine. however, the script itself is on a share network drive, so if we put the token in the script, then anyone on the network drive can read the token and use it to access the vault ID's and passwords that we put in the vault to hide in the first place. thanks for the answer tho!